# Laravel: custom functions in namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

Is it possible to have my helper functions in a namespace?

My current setup (that I cannot make work) is:

*app\Helpers\simple_html_dom.php:*

```php
<?php

namespace App\Helpers\HtmlDomParser;

function file_get_html(){
  echo 'file_get_html() called';
}
```

*composer.json*

```php
"autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/simple_html_dom.php",
            "app/Helpers/common.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
```

*app\Services\dde\dde_trait.php*

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services\dde;
use App\Helpers\HtmlDomParser;

trait ddeTrait{
  public function parse(){
    $content = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html();
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is *Class "App\Helpers\HtmlDomParser" not found.*

But that *HtmlDomParser* is not a class but a namespace.

Is the only correct setup to put the `file_get_html()` function into the HtmlDomParser class? Laravel version: 8+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define a class "HtmlDomParser", only the namespace "App\Helpers\HtmlDomParser". To call the function in this namespace use the full qualified version:

```
App\Helpers\HtmlDomParser\file_get_html().
```

You may consult this page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php

Comment: Better solution would be to alias the function at the beginning of the file. `use function App\Helpers\HtmlDomParser\file_get_html;` instead of their present `use App\Helpers\HtmlDomParser;`

Comment: `HtmlDomParser\file_get_html()` works if I use `App\Helpers\HtmlDomParser` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do like this.

1- remove namespace from helper file.

app\Helpers\simple_html_dom.php:

<?php

function file_get_html(){
  echo 'file_get_html() called';
}

2- your composer.json looks fine. just make sure you run below command after adding helper filein autoload section.

* composer du
* php artisan config:cache

3- call helper function directly without namespace in file app\Services\dde\dde_trait.php

namespace App\Services\dde;

trait ddeTrait{
  public function parse(){
    $finstat_content = file_get_html();
  }
}
```